# Device Ready ios not working

Tags: ios, cordova

I know this is repeated like ton of times but I cannot find the way to resolve it.
We have an app running in android with no problems.

But when I install it in my iphone the device ready does not get fired.

The device ready jumps  in android but in ios if auto-hide-splash-screen is  false it keeps stuck in the splashscreen and deviceready is not fired.

I am making the build with phonegap build.

The version of cordova is 3.7.0

the code of the device ready is

```
 document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    alert('listening to device ready'+navigator);
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();      
  }, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like :

```
var onLoad = function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceReady, false);
};

var deviceReady = function(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", exitCordova, false);
    alert('listening to device ready'+navigator);
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
};

var exitCordova = function(){
    navigator.app.exitApp();
};
```